# Difference in Differences with Month Variable

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multiple-regression, lme4-nlme, difference-in-difference

I am working on real world difference in differences (DiD) analysis in R for a non-profit and could use some help.

We are trying to compare the % of patients starting antenatal care in the first trimester in one community against a set of other comparable communities without an intervention.

My thinking is that we should be using a generalized linear mixed effects model (GLMM) using the glmer() function to include multiple observation of the same patients (multiple pregnancies) as a random effect. My pilot model thus far has been y = intercept + B1(Group) + B2(Treated) + B3(Group*Treated) + B4(Random Effects of resampling same patients) + B5(categorical Month) + error.

In R: `glmer(formula = y ~ com_type + tx_per + (com_type * tx_per) + factor(Month) + (1 | pt_id), data = df)`

Com_type = 1 for communities were the intervention occurred and 0 for a set of communities in which the intervention did not occur.

Tx_per = 1 for post-intervention and 0 for pre-intervention time period.

pt_id = patient id#.

Questions

1. Is the model correct? If not, any advice would be greatly appreciated.
2. Is the code correct? I have seen some papers discussing dropping the random effects terms when certain conditions are met. Is this advisable?
3. Should we include a random effect for community as well or is the fixed effect (0, 1) sufficient?